# Unknown error when trying to call flash method from javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, externalinterface

I have the following callback:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("wasCalledFromJS", callFromJavaScript);
```

which is implemented like this:

```
    public function callFromJavaScript(dir:String):void {
    try {
        scriptName = dir.toString();
    } catch (e:*) {
        Alert.show(e.toString());
    }
}
```

However, when I try to call it from the JS console, in the following way ( with the method defined in [How to call flash actionscript callback method from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657842/how-to-call-flash-actionscript-callback-method-from-javascript) ):

```
>>> thisMovie("Flex4TextArea1").wasCalledFromJS("1")

"Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error."
```

It appears as if the code if not even reaching my try/catch block. Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: After adding `Security.allowDomain("*");` it works. Why am I required to do this, even when testing on localhost? It is the same domain, is it not?

Comment: Are you viewing through http://localhost and not some path like C:/my_hosting_area/htdocs

Comment: It might be that I opened a local file, such as `c:/...`. Isn't c:/something considered local domain as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was caused because domain priviledges were not set.