# Is it possible to automate the embedded flash login by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Is it possible to automate the login in flash content by javascript or by any other way?
Can I simulate the mouse clicks in flash?

Comment: This is currently very hard to understand. Can you clarify what you want to do and what your situation is?

Comment: I have a login screen in flash content which is embedded in a web page, I want to pass the username and password to the login screen in flash through javascript. After authentication, it should take me to the home page of flash content.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Flash Action Script functions from JavaScript to pass. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657842/how-to-call-flash-actionscript-callback-method-from-javascript) answers that aspect.

Comment: I don't have the actionscript code. Is it possible to fill the values of flash login form and submit using javascript.

Comment: If you cannot edit the Flash file itself and don't have the source or any other documentation, there is no way for you to do it. Or, technically there is almost always a way, but it would require you to reverse engineer the Flash (decompile, edit and compile) to get the Javascript-to-ActionScript to work, but it is already a very difficult road.