# AS3 method call from javascript

Tags: actionscript-3, javascript, swfobject

I'm trying to call an AS3 function from Javascript via `SWFObject` when i try calling i get this error

`cannot call method 'js_method_to_call' of null`

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;   
var test_var = ExternalInterface.addCallback("js_method_to_call", moveto);

function moveto() {
gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 2")

}
```

and this is my HTML file where i'm using the SWFobject

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "myFlashContent1";
            swfobject.embedSWF("Test_CEO.swf", "containerid", "800", "600", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function fall(){
        alert("calling");
        try{
            var myobject = document.getElementById("containerid");
            myobject.js_method_to_call();
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }

        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="containerid">
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        </div>
         <input id="save file" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="fall();" />
</body>
```

Reference : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7658201/2260496)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this one by running this on **XAMPP** server

so yes i attached the swf file like this in my html file

```
<object id="myMovie" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test.swf" width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="test.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
</object>
```

Then i used the anchor tag to link it to the swf object

```
<a id="clicky" href="#">click</a>
```

Then i called this using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clik= document.getElementById("clicky");
    clik.addEventListener("click",function(){
        document.getElementById("myMovie").letsalertme();
    })
</script>
```

So whenever i click the anchor tag the `letsalertme()` function inside the swf file will get executed.

And this is my `.fla` file which contains the actionscript

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function alertMe():void {
gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene1");
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("letsalertme",alertMe);
```

So whenever i call the `letsalertme()` from `Javscript` this function will call the `alertMe` function where `scene1` will start playing.

**//edit: I achieved this without using swfobject**