# Tracking a button click in swf

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a swf which contains a button "contact us". I dont have the flash code / structure known to me. Is there any way I can track that button click in javascript?

Comment: nope unless you have coded in `actionscript` to pass/call a value.
[You can check this for further reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397911/as3-method-call-from-javascript)